# What is WKErrorWebViewInvalidated?

Tags: javascript, objective-c, cocoa, webkit, wkwebview

I have a WKWebView to which I send javascript via `-[WKWebView evaluateJavaScript:completionHandler:]` Periodically, the web view returns the following error:

`Error Domain=WKErrorDomain Code=3 "The WKWebView was invalidated" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=The WKWebView was invalidated`

The corresponding WKError seems to be WKErrorWebViewInvalidated, but the WKError.h only seems to say the following about this error:

```
@constant WKErrorWebViewInvalidated                Indicates that the WKWebView was invalidated.
```

Once I receive this error from the web view I can no longer execute any subsequent javascript and I need to throw the web view away and create a new one. I've searched online for more details on this error, but have not been able to find anything of substance. Can someone help explain what this error means and how I can debug what might be causing it. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I had this error with a web view that was detached from the view hierarchy. Make sure your `WKWebView` has a `superview` and a `window` while you run the script if you see this error.

Answer (score 0):

It means that the *web content process* has died. This is the process that runs the JavaScript and does the Networking part of the `WKWebView`.

Unfortunately this process is managed by WebKit and you have zero control over it. So if your device runs low on memory, there is a very good change that it will randomly kill a web content process. That is when you receive the `WKErrorWebViewInvalidated` error.

Comment: It was my understanding that if the web content process dies, you receive a `WKErrorWebContentProcessTerminated` error, and you get a `webViewWebContentProcessDidTerminate:` callback if you're running iOS 9+, neither of which I'm getting. This makes me think `WKErrorWebViewInvalidated` refers to something different than the process dying.